# Multiple URLs on one domain in IIS 6

Tags: iis-6, domain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Host Multiple Domains / Web Sites on one IIS6 Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/47165/how-to-host-multiple-domains-web-sites-on-one-iis6-server)

I'm a developer and only know the basics of IIS administration.

I want to give each of my clients a *personalized* URL to access my web site.  I have mySite.com and I would like to allow client A to acess the site via A.mySite.com and client B to use B.mySite.com.  These would all point the the mySite.com domain with the same ip address.

Can this be done in IIS?  Do I have to register new domains for each client? Are there other ways to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: This is a duplicate.  Have a look at this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/47165/how-to-host-multiple-domains-web-sites-on-one-iis6-server

Comment: This is not the same question at all.  The referenced question asks how to set up multiple sites on a single server.  I'm asking how to use different urls on a single domain.

Answer (score 2):

This needs to be handled at the DNS level: there should be records for A.mySite.com and B.mySite.com, pointing to the same IP address.

If all of them need to see the **same** web site, then you need not to configure anything: the default web site in IIS automatically responds to any host name it gets called with; if you're not using the default web site, you can still configure a single web site to answer multiple names.

If they need to see **different** web sites, you need to define different web site and configure them to answer the correct names.

More info [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324287).

Answer (score 1):

You can read this article: http://content.websitegear.com/article/subdomain_setup.htm

The important part of it it's the following:

> Microsoft Windows IIS : In case of
>   Internet Information Server (IIS),
>   create a new web site for the
>   subdomain using the IIS Manager, and
>   add the sub-domain (e.g.
>   subdomain.domain.com) as a new host
>   header value listening to the same IP
>   address as specified in the DNS entry.
>   The port is set to 80 (the default for
>   http requests). The host header can be
>   added by clicking on the advanced tab
>   next to the IP address configuration
>   for that web site application. If the
>   subdomain points to a subdirectory of
>   the web site for the domain, then set
>   the home directory for the subdomain
>   web site to the subdirectory. For
>   example, if the domain.com points to
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\ and the subdomain
>   needs to be setup for
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\subdomain, then the
>   directory for the subdomain website
>   should be set to
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\subdomain