# IIS site with multiple IPs?

Tags: iis-6

Is it possible to setup an IIS hosted site so that it is setup with multiple IPs? I'm not sure if this is practicle or if we should stick to a single IP per site. We are using IIS6 on Windows 2003

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to know if it is possible to setup a single site with multiple IP addresses. We have a machine with multiple IPs and I was asked if we can bind multiple IPs to a site. To tell your the truth, I am not sure why I was asked.

Comment: If you want to host multiple websites in IIS, have a look here also:  http://serverfault.com/questions/47165/how-to-host-multiple-domains-web-sites-on-one-iis6-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. When you go to the site bindings, you can specify which IP address you want to bind it to, along with a host name. Feel free to add as many combinations of IP addresses and hostnames as you like.

To do this, go to the Site Properties (right-click the site and choose Properties) and next to "IP Address" click the "Advanced" button. Add them by using the Add button on this screen.

Answer (score 1):

A single IIS site can have multiple bindings so that it is accessible on different IP:port combinations.

You can also have lots of sites on a single IIS host that are all bound using the same IP address where the host header is used to determine which site a request will route to.

Comment: I knew you could have multiple sites per IP, but wasn't sure about the other way around. Thanks for looking!